# Filtering the View Without Filtering Underlying Data - TABLEAU

Tags: tableau-api, calculation

[image]
In the above image, I have added a lookup calculation to limit the number of values on the x-axis.

Formula for Lookup : lookup(min(([Weeks out ])),0)

{Weeks out} is the x axis

Currently the range selected is -36 to 0.

There are values present for >0 but because of the lookup, it doesn't show up.

I want to show the total running sum on the 0th axis(this should include all the values available after 0)

adding tabular format for better understanding
[image]

Comment: If you set all weeks >0 to 0, moving everything >0 to occur in week0 effectively, does that solve the problem?

Comment: Hey, this logic worked partially. Thanks very much for the help! @AndyTARSols